# How to hide foundation top bar for large (desktop)?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am new to foundation. I have a top bar and I want to hide it for desktop because I have another menu for it.

I try to use **hide-for-large** class, but it didn't work for me.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please show your codes.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `.hide-for-medium-up`

Answer (score 0):

The class .topbar uses !important on the display property. To override this behaviour, add  the following to the bottom of your app.css file or app.scss file. Since its on the bottom of the file, it is given priority.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
  .topbar {
    display:none !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Foundation if your hide-for-large class isn't working, it could be that you are selectively include components and have not included the visibility classes in your app.scss file `@import "foundation/components/visibility";` , you need this for that class to work.